# Flutter Debugging UI Issues

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am developing a flutter app, and facing a weird problem. When i am using it on Emulator/Phone in Debug mode, the UI quality degrades. As soon as i reopen the app without debug mode, it gets back.
Now, this is causing a headache coz color shade codes get affected, and gradient looks real bad, ruining the overall look i see in debug mode.

Can anyone help ?

During active debugging :-
[image]

During normally running the debug apk :-
[image]

Comment: no one knows an answer to this ?

Comment: Another comment to bring it to the top